# Date/Time Insert in Ms access through c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
Query

public static String qry7 = "insert into Attendance(E_ID,DATE,TIMEIN)        
values(@eid,@date,@timein)";
```

I am trying to insert date in ms access database which has date in format(mm/dd/yyyy) while timein in( 24HR ), i am struggling to insert the values but it is giving me insert syntax error.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timein", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", E_ID);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

I hope this will clear my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `[DATE]` because its reserved word

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` is a *[reserved keyword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx)* on MS Access.

You should surrounding it  with brackets (`[ ]`). Like;

```
public static String qry7 = "insert into Attendance(E_ID, [DATE], TIMEIN) VALUES (@eid,@date,@timein)";
```